# JSP File is not detect user defined java files. Please resolve

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to use .java files into JSP. But it is not able to do so.
I don't know why user defined .java files are not detected in index.JSP.
Although, pre-defined java files I am able to use in index.JSP.

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image: ing .]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
   import="com.demo.help.MyTester" %>

<% MyTester test= new MyTester() %>
```

By this I just wanted to tell you to use page directive and import the class file from the package whereever you have defined it.

Here my class file name is MyTester.java which is located in package named com.demo.help and this package is inside src/main/resources folder.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer now I have edited it and this worked for me

Comment: I create a class under under 
package com.demo.help;

public class MyTester {

}



and used below code in JSP but still not worked

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
   import="com.demo.help.MyTester" %>

<% MyTester test= new MyTester() %>

Comment: Can you show me the folder structure so I can guide you more and in your answer  what I can see you haven't done is try it Connection con = new ConnectionProvider(); if the also it shows error then hover it and tell me whats the error

Comment: Actually there is a static method I have to call which is getConnection()
I will call like ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
but I was just checking It is not accessing ConnectionProvider.
Could you remote login using AnyDesk and take a Look?

Comment: Firstly just try in your jsp this ConnectionProvider conn = new ConnectionProvider(); is it showing any error? and secondly in your connectionprovider class change private to public

Comment: ConnectionProvider is already a public class.

I am using it as Utility class. So, I don't need object of this class.

You can't assign object of ConnectionProvider to Connection interface as below :(
Connection con = new ConnectionProvider();

ConnectionProvider class code for your reference below:


package com.jatin.learningblog.helper;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class ConnectionProvider {
 
 private static Connection con;
 public static Connection getConnection()
 {
  return con;
 }
}

Comment: In ConnectionProvider class do public static Connection con instead of private then try in jsp Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getConnection();

Comment: Still not working. I tried with public also.
if possible get remote access and crosscheck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218668/discussion-between-prateek-kumar-and-jatinder-verma).

Answer (score 0):

[I impoerted:
<%@page import="com.jatin.learningblog.helper.*"%>
then I am using.
But it is showing error, don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enjjg.png)

[Code of ConnectionProvider.java for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfu33.png)

Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import Java files into the jsp like that:

```
<%@page import="Model.Car, Services.*"%>
or
<%@page import="Model.Car"%>
<%@page import="Services.*"%>


<%Car bmw = new Car();%>
<%=bmw.id%>
<%CarServices.getBrand();%>
```

Comment: I have imported but not working. Even it is showing error in import that java class.
If possible take a look by remote control.